# Java Project Reactor/WebFlux token service

Tags: java, thread-safety, spring, reactive-programming

I'm trying to achieve a thread-safe reactive token service. The point is that all subscribers must wait until the token is received or updated (when expired). It works, but I want a second opinion about it's thread safety, as I'm not really sure how it should be done with reactive stack. The token lives 1 hour, but I update it 5000 ms before expiry.

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class TokenService {

    // time before real token expires
    // token expiry time calculated like this:
    // time = expiry_time - UPDATE_TOKEN_BEFORE
    // thus the token will be updated a bit earlier than it expires
    private static final int UPDATE_TOKEN_BEFORE = 5000;

    private final WebClient webClient;
    private final TokenConfiguration config;

    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private volatile String token;
    private volatile long expiresMillis;
    private volatile boolean hasToken = false;
    private volatile boolean loading = false;

    private final Sinks.Many<String> sink;

    public TokenService(WebClient webClient, TokenConfiguration config) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
        this.config = config;
        this.sink = Sinks.unsafe().many().replay().latest();
    }

    /**
     * Get the cached token or request a new one from the auth service.
     * Makes subscribers wait until the first one gets the token from the auth service, then supplies them with
     * already retrieved token.
     *
     * @return {@link Mono} of token string.
     */
    public Mono<String> getToken() {
        if (!hasToken || System.currentTimeMillis() >= expiresMillis) {
            if (!loading) {
                // flag that we're processing the token
                this.loading = true;
                return getTokenMono()
                        // update token & expiresMillis locally
                        .map(this::updateToken)
                        .map(token -> {
                            final Sinks.EmitResult result = sink.tryEmitNext(token);
                            // throw EmissionException if emitting fails
                            result.orThrow();
                            return token;
                        })
                        // finally, flag we're done processing
                        .doOnSuccess(i -> this.loading = false)
                        // if something goes wrong, flag that we should try again
                        .doOnError(i -> {
                            this.hasToken = false;
                            this.loading = false;
                        });
            }
        }
        // emit when the token gets ready
        return sink.asFlux().filter(token -> !token.isEmpty()).next();
    }

    /**
     * Invalidate the token.
     */
    public void invalidateToken() {
        this.hasToken = false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the token from the auth service.
     *
     * @return Mono of {@link TokenResponse}.
     */
    private Mono<TokenResponse> getTokenMono() {
        log.info("Retrieving the access token from upstream");
        return webClient.post()
                .uri(config.getTokenUrl())
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("grant_type", "credentials")
                        .with("client_id", config.getClientId())
                        .with("client_secret", config.getClientSecret()))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(TokenResponse.class);
    }

    /**
     * Update the token in this class and return it.
     *
     * @param response see {@link TokenResponse}
     * @return the token from {@code response}.
     */
    private String updateToken(TokenResponse response) {
        // make the token expire a few seconds before it is set to expire
        log.info("New token: {}", response);
        this.expiresMillis = (response.getExpiresIn() * 1000) + System.currentTimeMillis() - UPDATE_TOKEN_BEFORE;
        this.token = "Bearer " + response.getAccessToken();
        this.hasToken = true;
        return this.token;
    }
}
```